# Did Homo sapiens have children with Neanderthals?

Tags: genetics

One of my friends told me that Homo Sapiens and Neanderthals had children together when the homo sapiens came to Europe about 50 000 BC.

But is it possible that Homo Sapiens and Neanderthals had children together and bore children with mixed genes from both Homo Sapiens and Neanderthals ?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: Here's an example article from the BBC that makes the claim and only hints at the evidence behind it http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-35595661

Comment: The answer to this question includes some great evidence that this did happen. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19287/11643

Answer (score 5):

There's a [significant body of evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal#Interbreeding_with_modern_humans) for this claim. Eg:

> an analysis of a first draft of the Neanderthal genome by the same team released in May 2010 indicates interbreeding may have occurred.[1](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/8660940.stm),[2](https://dx.doi.org/10.1126%2Fscience.1188021) 
>   Those of us who live outside Africa carry a little Neanderthal DNA in
>   us," said Pääbo, who led the study. "The proportion of
>   Neanderthal-inherited genetic material is about 1 to 4 percent. It is
>   a small but very real proportion of ancestry in non-Africans today,"
>   says Dr. David Reich of Harvard Medical School, who worked on the
>   study. This research compared the genome of the Neanderthals to five
>   modern humans from China, France, sub-Saharan Africa, and Papua New
>   Guinea. The finding is that about 1 to 4 percent of the genes of the
>   non-Africans came from Neanderthals, compared to the baseline defined
>   by the two Africans [2](https://dx.doi.org/10.1126%2Fscience.1188021).

There is similar evidence of interbreeding with hominins other than Neanderthal too.